# I've created java for displaying current month automatically, but I'm trying to always display the next month along. E.g: If June - display "July"

Tags: javascript

I've managed to put together java for displaying the current month automatically (displayed below) but I'm trying to get a result of always showing the next month along. For example, It's June now - so I want to display "July". If it was August, I'd like to display "September".

**Here's the code for displaying the current month, automatically alternating:**

```js
{
  var month = new Array();
  month[0] = "January";
  month[1] = "February";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "August";
  month[8] = "September";
  month[9] = "October";
  month[10] = "November";
  month[11] = "December";
  var d = new Date();
  var n = month[d.getMonth()];
  document.write (month = n)
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Comment: `Java != JavaScript`

Comment: change to  var n = month[d.getMonth() + 1]; with necessary checks when value is 12

Comment: `(d.getMonth() + 1) % 12`

Comment: Just a little tip,  browsers already have month's etc built in, so your above code could be shortened, to -> `var d = new Date(); d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1); console.log(d.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'long'}))`  with the advantage is will work with other languages without you doing anything extra..

Comment: Thanks everyone! "var n = month[d.getMonth()+1];" worked just fine, even without referencing the 12 months. Thanks again! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create a few functions to help us out with this kind of problem. Namely `getMonthName`, `getNextMonth`, and `getNextMonthName` (a combination of the two!).

Using these, we can get the next month value as an integer, or as a month name.

The `locales` argument should be left as default to display in the client language, or perhaps something like `en-US`, `de-DE` to display as specific language.

We'd always pass Date.getMonth() to these functions, unless, perhaps we wanted to say, get the next month after December, e.g. getNextMonth(11);

```js
function getMonthName(month, locales = 'default') {
    return new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), month, 1).toLocaleString(locales, { month: 'long'} );
}

function getNextMonth(month) {
    return (month + 1) % 12;
}

function getNextMonthName(month, locales = 'default') {
    return getMonthName(getNextMonth(month), locales);
}

console.log("Current month name:", getMonthName(new Date().getMonth()))
console.log("Next month name:", getNextMonthName(new Date().getMonth()))

console.log("Current month name (German):", getMonthName(new Date().getMonth(), 'de-DE'))
console.log("Next month name (German):", getNextMonthName(new Date().getMonth(), 'de-DE'))

console.log(`Listing all months:`);
const months = [...Array(12).keys()];
for(let month of months) {
    console.log(`Month: ${getMonthName(month)}, next month: ${getNextMonthName(month)}`);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for all those options Terry, I really appreciate it! 

Comment: Happy to help!!